# How to share a notification in Android?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-sharing

I am having a notification, which has an action while clicking. I want to put a view (Imageview/TextView) in the notification. While clicking on this it should open an Intent Which allows you to share that notification's image & description(like, While taking screenshot, it asks you to share).Can anybody help to sort this out?